# What if I answer my own bounty question?

Tags: support, macos

I have been struggling with a python problem for several weeks. Recently I started a bounty on my question I had submitted. No one has answered yet but I have figured out the solution. May I answer my own bountied question?

Answer (score 1):

Bounty is designed to attract attention. You can choose to award it to anyone else or let the system award it if the criteria are met for half awarding.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

You always can and should self answer, bounty or not. Thanks so much for asking a great question and then promoting it.